# Why do i have to put military time instead of just "Hour + meridian" in js alarm clock?

Tags: javascript, html, alarm

I am trying to make an alarm with JS, it works fine but in order for it to work I need to put "17" for hours instead of "5 PM" which makes more sense. Take a look at the code here:

JS:

```
function soundAlarm() {

  var mer = document.getElementById('meridian').value;

  var h = document.getElementById('hourSelector').value;
  var m = document.getElementById('minuteSelector').value;

  alert("Successfully scheduled alarm!");

  setInterval(function(){
    var date = new Date();

    var hours = date.getHours();  
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();

    if (mer == "1"){
      hours = hours;
    }
    if (mer == "2"){
      hours = hours + 12;
    }
    if (h == hours && m == minutes){
      document.getElementById('ringtone').play();   
    }
  });}
```

HTML:

```
  <audio id="ringtone" src="SamsungS6Mp3Ringtones.mp3" autostart="false" repeat="true"></audio>  

  <div class="page">

    <span id="setAlarmTime"><u>Set Alarm Time</u></span>
    <br><br>
    <input type="number" id="hourSelector" placeholder="Hours...">
    <input type="number" id="minuteSelector" placeholder="Minutes...">
    <select id="meridian">
      <option value="1"> AM </option>
      <option value="2"> PM </option>
    </select>  
    <br><br>      
    <button onclick = "soundAlarm();" id="set"> Set </button>    

  </div>
```

Comment: wait i know the error

but it still not working

Comment: I know one of the errors :(

Comment: “5PM” only makes sense to Americans, **for the rest of the world** we all think 17:00 makes more sense :)

Comment: That is not my question

Comment: So what **is** your question then? You have to use the 24-hour clock because JavaScript's `Date` object returns hours as a `number` value in the range `0-23`, this is documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours (note that the term "military time" is US-specific and outside the US is **not** synonymous with using a 24-hour clock, this is explained in the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock - StackOverflow is an international website with users from around the world)

Comment: I already got it :)